# understanding the linear_extrude operator in OpenSCAD

Tags: scaletransform, openscad

In OpenSCAD, the linear_extrude operator takes a 2d shape and extrudes it into 3d, optionally twisting it.

For example:

```
linear_extrude(height = 40) {
  square(10);
}
```

However, I found in the wiki:
    linear_extrude(height = 30, center = true, convexity=10, scale=[1,2])
     square([20,10],center=true);

This one makes the "square" (which is actually a rectangle) bigger as it goes, scaling from 1 to 2.  But it does so only in one dimension.  I can't find how to make both dimensions scale equally, much less both dimensions scale differently.

The purpose in this case is to create a container that is not square, but gets wider towards the opening, necessary for ice cubes and molds for example so the material inside falls out easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scale = [1,2]` scales x with factor 1 and y with factor 2

`scale = 2` or `scale = [2,2]` scales both equally

Comment: Whoa! linear_extrude(height=30) { circle(10); } makes a cylinder.  The example I saw appeared to START with a scale of 1 and END with a scale of 2.  If that's not true, can it be controlled? It looks like it can be?

Comment: Right you are! initial scale is just 1.

Comment: and so your example of extruding a circle with scale([1,2]) changes the profile over the height of extrude from circle to ellipse (one of the little things why i like openscad)

Answer (score 1):

Linear extruder is actually less powerful that Hull command. Using hull, you can merge any two objects, and if you loop very many flat objects in a loop, hull 2 by 2 and union them, it's the same as extrude, with control of x-y-z scale and rotation of every individual segment of the extrusion. linear is only in a line and hull can generate the same result using spirals and so on.